# ImageView not honoring Picture settings on Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv, google-tv

I am creating a very simple test Android app on **Google TV** (the newest 2022 renamed Android TV platform, not the old 2012 Google TV platform.) My app displays an image (PNG) fullscreen using the **ImageView** control with all its default settings.

Goal: To display images like the stock **Media Center** or **YouTube** app -- images/VDOs displayed honor the **TV's Picture settings** (e.g. contrast, brightness, color, tint, sharpness, etc.)

Current situation: The image is displayed with the TV's standard picture settings and looks very washed out. Changing any of the Picture settings has no effect.

**In contrast, changing TV Picture settings works on VDOs played by YouTube and images displayed by Media Center**. For example, images/VDOs look green when I change the Tint setting to G50 (just for testing.) It doesn't affect the app itself (the app's font color, trim, etc. do not turn green.)

I simply want my app to work like the Media Center or YouTube app. Any tip would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some updates:
- Playing video files (I tested an mp4 file) using either VideoView or SurfarceView + MediaPlayer honors the TV Picture settings. So the video side is solved.
- Trying to 'cheat' by setting the background property of the working VideoView or SurfaceView control to an image doesn't work. The still image shows up, but will not honor the Picture settings and still looks washed out.

Comment: I believe I have arrived at an answer to my own question. I am not 100% so I will leave the question open.

It is likely that my new Android/Google TV only applies the Picture settings on VDOs or anything rendered through the hardware accelerated decoding engine. As such, VDO works, but pictures and App UIs do not I tried displaying images via Plex and Kodi and they are also subject to the same issues.

An exception is the stock Media Center app. It can somehow render PNGs through the hardware GPU at native 4K resolution and with Picture settings. I only wish I know how to do the same.